# Store and display image file in Apache Cassandra

Tags: http, cassandra, httpserver

I have read jpg/png file through string buffer using cassandra Hector APIs.
Now i want to show that file on html page.

Is there any way to show that file on html page without creating temporary file on local file system. Because I have set up Cassandra in Cluster mode and do not want to restrict me to one machine to store these temporary files.

Comment: retagged as this probably depends primarily on features of the web server. You essentially need to be able to serve an in-memory image via HTTP...

Comment: I'd also add that you probably want to represent it as a byte[] or ByteBuffer, not a String buffer.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have retrieved the image data, you have kind of service for serving the byte array of the image. 
You can map a servlet to certain URL(for ex. `/imagepreview`), in the URL you will have the id of the image. The id can be part of the path (in RESTful manner) or as URL parameter - it is your choice.

Next in your HTML file you can add image tag "img" and the "src" attribute will have the URL to the servlet with certain image id. Like this :

```
<img src="/imagepreview?id=83745"></img>
```

Here is simplified path of serving the request:

- The servlet will "know" how to read the image id
- it will use the image service to retrieve the image bytes
- it will full-fill the HTTP response with the bytes and will set the necessary headers.